# Installing modules in older python version fails with pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-3.6, importerror

I have python versions 2.7 and 3.8 in my laptop which I both need.
I need to change my python path into:

```
PYTHONPATH=$HOME/lib/python
```

Now, I am trying to install matplotlib and numpy for version 2.7:

```
$ python2.7 -m pip install matplotlib
/usr/bin/python2.7: No module named pip
```

Then:

```
$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

At this point I am confused. So I try:

```
$ pip install numpy
...
Successfully installed numpy-1.22.3
$ pip show numpy
<some path>/lib/python3.8/site-package
```

Which confuses me even more. Now running python:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar  8 2021, 13:02:45)
>> import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I am perhaps missing something very obvious or I've probably broken something in installation. I'm new in this version variability. How can I install packages for older versions in this environment?

Comment: It's the pip for your Python 3.8 interpreter. If `python` is resolving to the correct 2.7 interpreter, just use `python -m pip install numpy` instead

Comment: As an aside, you should probably be using virtual environments which keeps this sort of thing much more organized. I use `conda` but there are various different tools to choose from

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ```python -m pip install numpy``` does not work either, I want to use pip for the 2.7 interpreter

Comment: Turns out ```sudo apt install python-pip``` doesn't work since this version is deprecated. I suppose virtual environments are my only choice.